# DBML: s letter added to my table names

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using Visual Studio 2008

Each time I modify my dbml through the designer some of the table names in the designer.cs file are changed from `TableName` to `TableNames` leading to some reference errors in the rest of the project. The names that appear on the dbml are not changed.

Where does this come from ? Is it a setting ?

Edit: 
It happens to tables I have recently added through the designer and to all the tables that have a foreign key linking theme to these tables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was a setting:

Tools > Options > Database tools > O/R Designer

And then we have a `Pluralization of names` option that can be switched to :

> Enabled  **False**

Answer (score 2):

Its a feature. you may find this SO posting helpful [Why does "linq to sql classes" change the name of a table when making a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467614/why-does-linq-to-sql-classes-change-the-name-of-a-table-when-making-a-class)

Comment: In my case the name is not changed in the dbml but in the designer.cs file where the classes are defined.